# URLRequest in AS3 can't read the correct content when server return 403

Tags: actionscript-3, http-status-code-403, urlrequest, urlstream

I'm using URLRequest in a Flash client to get some information from a service, the service will check the parameter in the request url, if the parameter is invalid, the server may return 403 with some content in http body, and I need analyse the content, the content is a json string:

```
{"code":3, "msg":"invalid channel"}
```

Unfortunately, sometimes the URLRequest can't read the content from URLStream, stream.bytesAvailable is 0, seems that the URLStream read null data.
Is there any bug in URLRequest? Or it just because I'm using it in the wrong way?

Here's the code:

```
    public function test() {
        stream = new URLStream();
        request = new URLRequest(url);
        configureListeners(stream);
        var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000, 10);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
        timer.start();
    }

    private function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
        request.url = url + "&timestamp=" + getTimer();
        trace("try to load: " + request.url);
        stream.load(request);
    }

    private function configureListeners(dispatcher:EventDispatcher):void {
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
    }

    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("completeHandler: " + event);
        parseHeader();
    }

    private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
        trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event.toString());
        trace(stream.bytesAvailable + ", " + event.target.bytesAvailable + ", " + event.target.length);
    }
```

Here's the log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgtAD.png)

Comment: You request data 10 times each 2 seconds through the only instance of **URLStream**. Basically, you can issue another request before previous one is complete - that alone could be the root of the multiple errors. Personally I advise against reusing instances of **URLLoader**, **URLStream** and such like **at all**. So: 1) wait for one operation to complete (or to fail) before requesting the next one and 2) do not reuse **URLStream** instances, create new ones.

Comment: You could try looking in the [HTTPStatusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html#responseHeaders) response header object: `event.responseHeaders` - might find your data there.

Comment: This should work with AIR (listen for `HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS` and if you determine it's a status code that should have a response, it should exist when you get to the ioError handler).  If using flash as a plugin, it's not likely ever going to work like you want.  With non 2xx response codes, most people using flash in this situation return a 200 with an error flag/message in the response.

Comment: @Orgains Thanks, it's just a test demo so reuse URLStream seems not so perfect —— but that's not the key point, even in the first request, I can see the msg in the browser, but  URLStream read nothing. So I think there must be something wrong.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Maybe you are right, URLStream can't read proper content in non 2xx responses. I'm asking this question to find out what's the root reason: URLStream doesn't support this situation, or I'm using it unproperly, or is there any better interface to meet this need. Now it seems that URLStream caused this problem. So maybe the best solutioin is changing the response code to 200.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to load (when you're not getting a 403)?   UrlStream is for binary data and I've never actually had need to use it in any of my AIR projects in the past decade.

Comment: **URLStream** is, as name suggests, for streaming data. If you just need the whole content at once, use **URLLoader**.

Comment: @Organis the content is binary data, however, I tried to use URLLoader instead, but the result is the same: most of the time URLLoader can read 0 bytes...

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis the content is binary data, however, I tried to use URLLoader instead, but the result is the same: most of the time URLLoader can read 0 bytes...

Comment: @CuiLipeng Ok, question. If you request this URL any other way, like, directly in browser, does it always work and output correctly?

Comment: @Organis yes, the output is correct, to verify this I used Flash Builder to debug the demo, I can see the content length is 33Bytes in the browser while the console shows URLLoader.bytesTotal is 0, however, sometimes it's 33, but these requests in the browser seems nothing different.